# Can a C++20 co-routine implement a synchronous interface without blocking?

Tags: boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am writing a GRPC service and am trying to use the asynchronous methods with the help from Asio. The service calls into a C++ library that have synchronous methods. The code in that library uses interfaces that must be implemented by the user of the library. These interfaces contains synchronous methods.

I wish to implement these interfaces by using asynchronous GRPC calls to other services. My challenge is that I cannot see how I can implement an adaptor between the synchronous - and asynchronous world. Is this at all possible in C++?

In (my) theory I want this co-routine adaptor to send the GRCP request and then the thread should continue executing other co-routines - and not be blocking - while waiting for the GRPC reply. When the reply is received the synchronous method call is returned to the library. This way I would be able to implement my GRPC service with only one thread and I do not have to worry about multi-threading issues.

When using co_await in a method then the return value is reflecting the async nature of the method, so I cannot use co_await (directly) when implementing a synchronous interface. Instead I can post a lambda containing the co_wait, but then I have to do a blocking wait on a future (or similar) and my single threaded service is deadlocked. I have been thinking of using co_yield and make a type of generator since it seems to be that the consumer of these generators can be synchronous.

Best regards

Comment: The generic answer regarding connecting async-async or sync-async is to use a FIFO inbetween.,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I see it the GRPC connection can be regarded as a FIFO in this context. My problem is then if I can avoid the blocking wait on the FIFO so that the thread can process the FIFO instead.

Comment: Can't you poll on the FIFO from the async thread, instead of doing a blocking read?

Comment: Maybe. I guess this is my question. I know I can do what I want if I spawn more threads and use mutexes. I just want to investigate if I can implement my service with only one thread. So the async thread is also the thread calling into the interface with the synchronous signature. So I am investigating if I can do the processing of the FIFO instead of blocking. For example if the waiting for the future could return the thread to Asio to process messages until the result was ready.

Comment: Is your question just "how to wait for a completion handler synchronously without blocking other async handlers?" Maybe it would help if you provided an example of one of the synchronous methods of the interface you're trying to implement.

Comment: My question applies to all synchronous methods. That is interface-methods that do not return an **Awaitable** type, such as `double get_value()`. So I want the implementation of `get_value` request the value from another service and let the thread continue processing the Asio event loop while waiting for the result.